A question about simulation speed in Proteus 8
Fig 1 In Figure 1, the PA8 pin of the STM32 in the upper-left corner is disconnected from the control terminal of the transmission gate formed by the MOS. After starting the simulation, the speed remains normal, and the PWM waveform generated by the PA8 pin functions correctly.Fig 2However, in Figure 2, when I connected PA8 to the control side of the transmission gate, the simulation slowed down significantly. While 1 second passed in real time, less than 0.000001 seconds elapsed in the simulation. Additionally, the CPU load increased from 12% to 67% between the two simulations.
I believe my circuit is functioning correctly since the two pins work fine when they're not connected. However, I'm puzzled as to why the simulation slows down significantly when they are connected. Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this?

I’m voting to close this question because 1. It is not a programming question. 2.. It des not follow the question guidelines.
